# Finding difference of two columns with where clause - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join, difference

I'm trying to get the difference of two columns(**OTHER** AND **SENIOR**) with WHERE clause along with the Sum of their amount. The formulas are working fine, however, I'm not getting the result I want.

I tried to do it using **INNER JOIN** and unfortunately its not the result that I expected

Here's my query:

```
select a.ID as EMPLOYEE, 
sum(a.amount) as other,
sum(b.amount) as senior, 
(sum(a.amount) - sum(b.amount)) as result 
from gndsale a 
INNER join gndsale 
b ON a.ID= b.ID 
where a.TYPE = "5" and b.seniortype = "10" 
group by a.ID
```

Result:

[image]

What I want to do is get the difference of **Column (Other) where type = 5 and Column (Senior)  where seniortype = 10**

Here is my query for Senior:

```
 select ID as EMPLOYEE, sum(amount) 
 from gndsale 
 where seniortype = "10" 
 group by ID
```

Result:

[image]

Here is my query for Other:

```
select ID as employee, sum(amount) 
from gndsale 
where type = "5" 
group by ID
```

[image]

The result should be

**9907 = 530 

9912 = 63.71**

Anyone can help me with this? :(

Sample/Expected output:

[image]

Comment: Can you post database schema with some sample data and expected result?

Comment: Hi Bikash, to be honest, the data tables that were given to me are not organized and its my task to find the result using a sample excel report.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: what i understand is you want to get difference of `other` and `senior` where type=5 and seniortype=10. if i am getting it wrong please explain.

Comment: @RahulSingh that's correct

Comment: where is primary key. is it on `employee` or `ID`

Comment: @RahulSingh its on ID, I just rename the ID as employee

Comment: _Edit_ your question and show sample input and output.  That both answers given below didn't meet what you expect, I'd conclude that you never made your expectations clear.

Comment: Exactly. I believe that you can do it without self join, but need some sample data and expected output based on that to confirm it.

Comment: adding a sample output... However, I'll put it as an excel sheet... updating...

Comment: If `ID` were the table's primary key as one would expect and as you say is the case, then the query could not give you the result you are showing, as you'd simply join each record to itself and `a.amount` would always equal `b.amount`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  but they are indicated in specific types.... senior is for seniortype and other is for type only. Is there someway to compute this using those types only?

Comment: added expected output

Comment: @Virgil Cruz: With one `ID`: will I find exactly one record in the table? Or can there be multiple records with the same `ID`?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner there are multiple records with one ID, that's why I used SUM and group by

Comment: This is what I am saying: `ID` is **not** the table's primary key. A primary key uniquely identifies a record.

Comment: All this would become much clearer, if you didn't only post results, but also the table data these results stem from. Can there be multiple records for one ID and type = 5? Can there be multiple records for one ID and seniortype = 10?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner sorry about that... yes, there are multiple records for one ID where type = 5 and there multiple records for one ID as well for seniortype = 10....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have chosen a very bad name for the column. In spite of its name `ID` is not an ID to identify a record in the table.

You are probably looking for something like the following, an aggregation per ID where you sum type 5 and seniortype 10 separately:

```
select 
  a.ID as employee, 
  coalesce(sum(case when type = 5 then amount end), 0) as other, 
  coalesce(sum(case when seniortype = 10 then amount end), 0) as senior, 
  coalesce(sum(case when type = 5 then amount end), 0) -
  coalesce(sum(case when seniortype = 10 then amount end), 0) as result
from gndsale
group by a.id
having sum(type = 5) > 0 and sum(seniortype = 10) > 0;
```

(The `HAVING` clause ensures only to get IDs that have both records with type = 5 and seniortype = 10. We use MySQL's `true = 1` / `false = 0` here. Remove it, if you want other IDs, too. If you keep it and value cannot be null, then you can remove the coalesces instead.)

Comment: This got my result that I'm looking for!!! that took me for hours... Thanks Thorsten and sorry if I didnt make my problems clear earlier...

Answer (score 0):

You might give this a try:

```
SELECT 
    a.`employee`,
    sum(a.`amount`) - sum(b.`amount`) as total
FROM `gndsale` a
JOIN `gndsale` b
ON a.`employee` = b.`employee` and b.`senior_type` = "10"
WHERE a.`type` = "5"
GROUP BY a.`employee`
ORDER BY a.`employee`;
```

It simply joins your two queries.

Comment: sorry it didnt gave me the result I wanted :( 
9907 = 1987.60  and 9912 = 20.47

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query

```
select employee, other, senior, (other-senior) AS result
From (
    select ID as employee,
           sum(if(type=5,amount,0)) AS other,
           sum(if(seniortype =10,amount,0)) AS senior 
           from gndsale group by ID
) a
```